# Detailed documentation for systemd's sd-bus

Tags: linux, ipc, dbus, systemd

I have some project which uses libdbus for IPC.
The goal is to use systemd's sd-bus instead of libdbus.

There is documentation for sd-bus ([here](http://0pointer.net/blog/the-new-sd-bus-api-of-systemd.html), [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd-bus.html) and etc), but that documentation doesn't cover all aspects of D-Bus specification implementation.

I spent a lot looking for at least any detailed explanation of sd-bus' implementation, but didn't find anything that could help me map libdbus' process workflow onto sd-bus.

Anybody can help me? Some unofficial docs, sequences, anything...

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? It's just... another way to communicate using D-Bus.

Comment: Exactly, it's another way to communicate between processes. In order to support sd-bus instead of liibdbus in my project, I need to better understand what sd-bus does, what API it provides and what those APIs do, relating to inter-process communication. Like, how it handles messages, which API should I call for message callbacks to be called, how do I register/unregister bus sinks, etc. It would be awesome if current documentation had these topics covered.

Comment: @Yeheshuah In the hope that this does not come over as negative propaganda: Your best hope is to directly call out to upstream and ask. Because ... from experience ... both source-code level documentation and developer-level documentation of systemd is ... highly superficial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [an upstream issue open for this already](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/235). I suggest you subscribe to that, and help out if you can.